# Partial Trace of Density Operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator, trace

To find the reduced density matrix, $\rho_A$, of a composite quantum system with two subsystems A and B, I've seen that the procedure is to take the partial trace of the full density matrix, $\rho_{AB}$, w.r.t the states of subsystem B;

$$ \rho_A = tr_B(\rho_{AB}) = \sum_i ⟨i_B|\rho_{AB}|i_B⟩  $$

However, on page 106 of 'Quantum Computing and Quantum Information' by Nielsen and Chuang, it is stated that

$$ tr(|b_1⟩⟨b_2|) = ⟨b_2|b_1⟩ $$

should there be a factor of 2 in this equation? This is repeated later as well, so I assume I am wrong.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you think there should be a factor $2$ in the first place? It seems to me that your question is not specific to the partial trace, but you're rather asking why something like $\mathrm{Tr} |\psi\rangle \langle \psi| = \langle \psi|\psi\rangle$, no?

Comment: @Jakob I was thinking that tr(|b1⟩⟨b2|)=∑i(⟨bi|b1⟩⟨b2|bi⟩)=⟨b1|b1⟩⟨b2|b1⟩+⟨b2|b1⟩⟨b2|b2⟩=2⟨b2|b1⟩. I understand Lucas' solution but if you could explain why what I did is wrong that would be helpful.

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107486/trace-in-non-orthogonal-basis) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation seems to be about the trace over the space of the $\vert b_j \rangle$, so that it evaluates to
\begin{align}
tr(|b_1⟩⟨b_2|) 
&= \sum_i \langle i \vert ( \vert b_1 \rangle \langle b_2 \vert ) \vert i \rangle \\
&= \sum_i \langle i \vert b_1 \rangle \langle b_2 \vert i \rangle \\
&= \sum_i \langle b_2 \vert i \rangle \langle i \vert b_1 \rangle \\
&= \langle b_2 \vert \left( \sum_i \vert i \rangle \langle i \vert \right) \vert b_1 \rangle \\
&= \langle b_2 \vert b_1 \rangle,
\end{align}

where $\{\vert i \rangle \}$ is a basis for the Hilbert space in which the $\vert b_j\rangle $ are in.

So no extra factor of 2.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up my question! Do you know why we can write the $tr_B(|a_1⟩⟨a_2|  ⊗ |b_1⟩⟨b_2|)$ as  $tr(|b_1⟩⟨b_2|)$ ?

Comment: @Angus You probably should check the definition of $\mathrm {Tr}_B$ (i.e. the partial trace) again.

Comment: @Lucas Baldo Could you explain what exactly you mean with *total trace*? I think here the $\mathrm{Tr}$ denotes only the trace in the subsystem $B$, since $|b\rangle \in \mathscr B$ (i.e. the Hilbert space of the subsystem $B$).

Comment: @Jakob yes, you're probably right. I meant the space that the $\vert b_i \rangle $ belong to. I couldn't tell this was a subsystem of a bipartite system without looking at the reference.

Comment: @Jakob Ahh yes, I misunderstood the 'total trace' as a trace over the whole system rather than the subsystem to which $|bi⟩$ belong, so was slightly confused with what Lucas had done, but this makes sense now.